# Render an image in an ExtJS4 grid qtip/tooltip

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Is it possible to render an image in an extJS4 qtip for a grid cell? I've tried the following code:

```
// col defs here
{
    text     : 'File Name',
    width    : 75,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex: 'filename',
    renderer: function(value,metaData,record,colIndex,store,view) { 
        metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="<img src=\"img.jpg\">"';
        return value;
    }
},
```

It seems incorrect to assign an html tag to an attribute, but I can't think of any other approach. In any event; it's not working. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have tried seems a good approach - how exactly is it not working? (Maybe you just need to define an absolute URL for the image?) Anyways, another (and a bit cleaner) option would be to assign a CSS class to the metadata object, and define the image URL in CSS.

Comment: You're right it does work. I was seeing an empty box because the image hadn't finished loading; oops. BTW, the second approach that you mention also works; but suffers from the drawback of getting a repeated image if the width/height of the div is too large. Thanks!

Comment: Image will not be repeated if you use the `no-repeat` CSS attribute.